# How does wikimedia code there input onfocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://wikimediafoundation.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Home

Wikimedia has a special onfocus on there input fields.

I tried to make them with a border:

```css
    input.small:focus {
        outline: none;
        padding-left: 0.5%;
        border-left: 5px solid #f00000;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0;
    }
input.big{
        height:50px;
    }
input.big:focus {
        outline: none;
        padding-left: 0.5%;
        border-left: 10px solid #f00000;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<input class='small'></br>
<p>Here you can see the diagonal line better.</p>
<input class='big'>
```

But this doesn't give the wanted result, it also seem that the css does not change if I do an inspect element.

So I think this must be javascript or jquery, but how?

So how do they do this?

Comment: It works when I run the code. What, precisely, is the problem?

Comment: If you look at the link how wikimedia does it, you see that it isn't a border because with a border it slightly goes diagonal near the end and wikimedia doesn't have this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lftct9rf/ Its CSS3...

Comment: I have no idea how you found the code but that's exacly what I was trying to say!

Comment: Check http://imgur.com/FQXe08P for how I found it. Its all there in the chrome dev tools... Trick is to emulate focus event by selecting at the top  :)

Comment: Yes I see, I didn't know that you had to active that. Thanks for every single time I'm going to use this in the future & you can answer the question becuse you got the one I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code directly scraped from their page. Its CSS3 and no javascript involved.

```css
.mw-ui-input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .3em .3em .3em .6em;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
  -moz-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
  -o-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
  transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
}

.mw-ui-input:focus {
  box-shadow: inset .45em 0 0 #347bff;
  border-color: #898989;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<input class="mw-ui-input">
```